# separate colours for ggplot geom_point and geom_seg

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `ggplot()` to plot a `betadispers` object `mod1` so that I can better control the colours.

I extracted the centroids from `mod1` and I am using `geom_point()` for plotting the yearly replicates for each dune , `geom_seg()`to plot the lines for each dune-star, and a second `geom_point()` statement to plot the centroids.
When I plot this using 
`scale_colour_manual(values=cols, guide= FALSE)`
it only changes the colour of the first geom_points and the geom_seg but not the centroids.

How do I control the colour of each component separately such that the dune points are coloured by `cols`, the segments are coloured by `cols1` and the centroids use `cols2`?
 I'd also like to change the colour of the black outline for each centroid to `cols1`.

```
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)

cols = c("blue","red")
cols1 = c("green","dark orange")
cols2 = c("purple","yellow")

data(dune)
sites = data.frame(year = rep(c(1:5), times= 4), dune = rep(c(1:4),each=5), dune.type = rep(c("A","B"),each=10))
distances <- vegdist(dune, method = "bray")

#create Betadispersion model on betad (effectively a PCoA)
mod1 <- with(sites, betadisper(distances, dune, type = "centroid"))
s = scores(mod1)

# Get points
pnt_sites = as.data.frame(s$sites)
pnt_sites = cbind(pnt_sites, sites)

# Get centroids
pnt_centroids = as.data.frame(s$centroids)
pnt_centroids$dune = rownames(pnt_centroids)
pnt_centroids$dune.type = rep(c("A","B"),each=2)

# Calculate segments
seg = pnt_sites[, c("PCoA1", "PCoA2", "dune")]
tmp = rename(pnt_centroids, c("PCoA1" = "PCoA1_ctr", "PCoA2" = "PCoA2_ctr"))
seg = join(seg, tmp, "dune")

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = pnt_sites,
    aes(x = PCoA1, y = PCoA2, colour = dune.type, shape = dune.type),
    size = 2
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = seg,
    aes(x = PCoA1, y = PCoA2, xend = PCoA1_ctr, yend = PCoA2_ctr, colour = 
       dune.type)
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = pnt_centroids,
    aes(x = PCoA1, y = PCoA2, fill = dune.type),
    size = 3, shape = 21
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=cols, guide= FALSE) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only specify `scale_colour_manual()` once per plot, not multiple times for each geom_point call, so you need to combine your centroids and sites into one dataframe (adding variables for centroid/site, and centroid A/centroid B/site A/site B), then plot as a single `geom_point()` layer

```
#combine centroids and points into one dataframe
pnt_centroids$year = NA
pnt_centroids$data.type = "centroid"
pnt_sites$data.type = "site"
sites_centroids <- rbind(pnt_centroids, pnt_sites)
sites_centroids$type <- paste(sites_centroids$data.type, sites_centroids$dune.type)
```

When you define vectors of colors to use for `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_colour_manual`, each will have 6 levels, to match the number of variables you have (4 point types plus 2 segment types).  Your site points and segments do not have a fill attribute, so fill will be ignored when plotting those points and segments, but you still need to define 6 colors in `scale_fill_manual` so that your filled points for centroids plot properly.

```
#change the cols vector definitions at the beginning of code to this
cols.fill <- c("purple", "yellow", "purple", "yellow", "purple", "yellow")
cols.colour <- c("green", "dark orange", "green", "dark orange", "blue", "red")
```

Specify the new colour, fill, and shape scales in the plot code like this:

```
# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_segment( #segment must go before point so points are in front of lines
    data = seg,
    aes(x = PCoA1, y = PCoA2, xend = PCoA1_ctr, yend = PCoA2_ctr, colour = dune.type)) +
  geom_point(
    data = sites_centroids,
    aes(x = PCoA1, y = PCoA2, colour = type, fill = type, shape = type), size = 2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols.colour) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols.fill, guide = FALSE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 21, 16, 17)) + 
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

Here is the result. The legend gets a bit busy, it may be better to delete it and use text annotation to label the dune types.

[image]